# Get continuous screen position off item being dragged (ItemTouchHelper)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag

Im using an ItemTouchHelper to create a draggable and swipable recyclerview (detailed here https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo.

I've looked through all the methods of ItemTouchHelper and ItemTouchHelper.callback and no method seems to give me the real time screen position of either my finger or the item while its being dragged. If anyone can help it would be a life saver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also look in the internal OnInterceptTouchEvent method of ItemTouchHelper for feedback

```
 private final RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener mOnItemTouchListener
        = new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent event) {
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "intercept: x:" + event.getX() + ",y:" + event.getY() + ", " + event);
        }
        final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, 0);
            mInitialTouchX = event.getX();
            mInitialTouchY = event.getY();
            obtainVelocityTracker();
            if (mSelected == null) {
                final RecoverAnimation animation = findAnimation(event);
                if (animation != null) {
                    mInitialTouchX -= animation.mX;
                    mInitialTouchY -= animation.mY;
                    endRecoverAnimation(animation.mViewHolder, true);
                    if (mPendingCleanup.remove(animation.mViewHolder.itemView)) {
                        mCallback.clearView(mRecyclerView, animation.mViewHolder);
                    }
                    select(animation.mViewHolder, animation.mActionState);
                    updateDxDy(event, mSelectedFlags, 0);
                }
            }
        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            wdwdwd
            mActivePointerId = ACTIVE_POINTER_ID_NONE;
            select(null, ACTION_STATE_IDLE);
        } else if (mActivePointerId != ACTIVE_POINTER_ID_NONE) {
            // in a non scroll orientation, if distance change is above threshold, we
            // can select the item
            final int index = MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(event, mActivePointerId);
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "pointer index " + index);
            }
            if (index >= 0) {
                checkSelectForSwipe(action, event, index);
            }
        }
        if (mVelocityTracker != null) {
            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
        }
        return mSelected != null;
    }
```

Comment: You should merge your two answers into one.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to go into the Recyclerview V7 jar and take the code from ItemTouchHelper and create my own version of ItemTouchHelper:
I added my own method to ItemTouchHelper.Callback

```
        public abstract void onTouchMovement(MotionEvent touch_event, int directionFlags, int pointerIndex);
```

I call onTouchMovement in the updateDxDy method of ItemTouchHelper:

```
 public void updateDxDy(MotionEvent ev, int directionFlags, int pointerIndex) {
    final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, pointerIndex);
    final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, pointerIndex);

    mCallback.onTouchMovement(ev, directionFlags, pointerIndex);
```

Now when ever I create a ItemTouchHelper.Callback it comes with OnTouchMovement which provides the position at every point of a drag/swipe